Temperature profile in a pipe flow with Matlab pdepe solver
I’m currently trying to solve the heat equation for the Ohmic heating of a pipe flow using the MATLAB pdepe solver. The problem is described in the following paper: https://doi.org/10.4236/ojmsi.2021.91002. This paper also contains the solution for the axial bulk temperature profile. Unfortunately, I don't find the same solution, and I wonder if anyone could help me find the error.
The simplified heat equation for this case becomes:
\begin{equation}
\rho C_p v_z\frac{\partial T}{\partial z} = \frac{k}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r \frac{\partial T}{\partial r}\right) + \hat{Q}.
\end{equation}
$\hat{Q}=\sigma E^2$ is the heat source due to the Ohmic heating (this is also defined in the paper). $v_z = 2V_{avg}(1-(\frac{x}{D/2})^2)$ is the classical solution for the axial velocity of the fluid in the pipe.
Please find the values of the constants in the code below.
The boundary conditions are:
\begin{equation}
T(z=0,r) = 40°C, \\
\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}|_{z,r=0} = 0,  \\ 
-k\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}|_{z,r=D/2} = h(T(z,r=D/2)- T_\infty). 
\end{equation}
Please find my Matlab code below. Note that in order to be able to use the Matlab pdepe solver, the time argument in the solver corresponds with the axial coordinate $z$. Another important remark is that I want to solve it with the option $m=0$.
Any help/comments/remarks will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
%% Main code
m=0;                         
r=linspace(0,0.025,1000);    % m    r corresponds with x 
z=linspace(0,2.5,1000);      % m    z corresponds with t 

sol=pdepe(m,@pdex1pde,@ic1pde,@bc1pde,r,z); 
u=sol(:,:,1);               % u=T 

% Figure I'm trying to recreate
figure 
plot(z,u(:,1))  
title('Axial bulk temperature distribution') 
xlabel('z') 
ylabel('T(z,r=0)')   

%% Functions
% Definition of the PDE
function [c,f,s]=pdex1pde(x,t,u,DuDx)
% Parameters 
T_0=40;             %°C 
k=0.6178;           % W/m*°C 
rho=992.2;          % kg/m^3   
C_p=4182;           % J/kg*°C 
m=82.5/3600;        % kg/s 
R=25*10^(-3);       % m 
D=50*10^(-3);       % m 
A=pi*R^2;           % m^2 
V_gem=m/(rho*A);    % kg m 
k_0=0.015;          % 1/°C^3 /s 
elec_cond=0.998*(1+k_0*(u-T_0));      % S/m 
v_z=2*V_gem*(1-(x^2/(D/2)^2));        % kg m^3 /s 
Volt=2304;          % V 
L=2.5;              % m  
Q=(elec_cond*(Volt/L)^2)*x/k); 

c=(rho*C_p*v_z*x/k);      
f=x*DuDx;                       
s=Q; 
end  

% "Initial" condition
function u0=ic1pde(x) 
u0=40;      
end 

% Boundary conditions
function [pl,ql,pr,qr]= bc1pde(xl,ul,xr,ur,t)  
% Parameters 
T_amb=20;          % °C 
T_0=40;            % °C 
h=10;              % W/m^2*°C 
k=0.6178;          % W/m*°C 

pl=0;               % left is ul=0    
ql=1;               % p+qf=0 
pr=h*(ur-T_amb); 
qr=k/xr;  
end 

 

